# regex to add a ? at the end of non-punctuated sentences

Tags: regex, editpad, powergrep

I'm looking for a regex formula to add a ? at the end of all non-punctuated sentences in a text document. I want to do this in edit pad pro or Power GREP.

**for ex**

Lichen planus occurs most frequently on the

A.  buccal mucosa.
B.  tongue.
C.  floor of the mouth.
D.  gingiva.

In the absence of “Hanks balanced salt solution”, what is the most appropriate media to transport an avulsed

A.  Saliva.
B.  Milk.
C.  Saline.
D.  Tap water.

Which of the following is the most likely cause of osteoporosis, glaucoma, hypertension and peptic ulcers in a 65 year old with Crohn’s disease

A.  Uncontrolled diabetes.
B.  Systemic corticosteroid therapy.
C.  Chronic renal failure.
D.  Prolonged NSAID therapy.
E.  Malabsorption syndrome.

**DESIRED RESULT**

Lichen planus occurs most frequently on the?

A.  buccal mucosa.
B.  tongue.
C.  floor of the mouth.
D.  gingiva.

In the absence of “Hanks balanced salt solution”, what is the most appropriate media to transport an avulsed?

A.  Saliva.
B.  Milk.
C.  Saline.
D.  Tap water.

Which of the following is the most likely cause of osteoporosis, glaucoma, hypertension and peptic ulcers in a 65 year old with Crohn’s disease?

A.  Uncontrolled diabetes.
B.  Systemic corticosteroid therapy.
C.  Chronic renal failure.
D.  Prolonged NSAID therapy.
E.  Malabsorption syndrome.

Comment: Downvote: What are you asking? Are you trying to find a regex which adds question marks to all non-punctuated sentences?

Comment: yes.thats exactly what i need.

Comment: What have you tried so far? `(\w)$` -> `\1?`

Comment: thnx works perfectly

Answer (score -1):

You really don't need code of any kind for that - just a *wildcard* Find/Replace, where:

```
Find = ([!.])( [A-Z].)
Replace = \1?\2
```

You could, of course, implement the above as a macro or some other script, but it hardly seems worth the effort.